# Stone's theorem and the spectral theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

I am struggling to formally derive the expression found in the Stone's theorem for one-parameter unitary groups. I am aware that this can be done by using the spectral theorem. I am mostly interested in the discrete 'version' of the spectral theorem.

Here's a short statement of Stone's theorem:

If ${\cal H}$ is a Hilbert space and $U(t)$ is a strongly-continuous,
one-parameter unitary group, then $U(t)=\exp\bigl(-itH\bigr)$, where
$H$ is self-adjoint.

Can anyone help me out or point me to some reference where this is explicitly done?

Comment: What do you mean by "discrete version" of the spectral theorem?

Comment: By discrete I mean the case in which an operator in question has a purely discrete spectrum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard reference is *Reed, Simon. Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics I*. Stone's theorem is treated in Section VIII.4.

The rough idea is as follows. Define a (possibly unbounded) operator $H$ by
$$
D(H)=\left\{\xi\in \mathcal{H}\mid\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\xi-U(t)\xi}{it}\phantom{x}\text{  exists }\right\},\ \ \ H\xi=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\xi-U(t)\xi}{it}.
$$

It needs some effort, but one can show that $H$ is self-adjoint. Then one can check that if $\xi\in D(H)$, both $u_1(t)=U(t)\xi$ (by the group property of $U$) and $u_2(t)=\exp(-itH)\xi$ (by the spectral theorem) solve the initial-value problem
\begin{align*}
\dot u(t)&=-iHu(t),\\
u(0)&=\xi.
\end{align*}
In particular,
$$
\|u_1(t)-u_2(t)\|^2=\int_0^t\frac{d}{ds}\|u_1(s)-u_2(s)\|^2\,ds=-2\int_0^t\operatorname{Re}i\langle u_1(s)-u_2(s),H(u_1(s)-u_2(s)\rangle\,ds=0.
$$
Thus $U(t)\xi=\exp(-itH)\xi$. The equality for arbitrary $\xi\in\mathcal{H}$ follows by continuity.

I do not know how purely discrete spectrum for the generator can be detected from the unitary group.

Comment: thanks a lot! I think i can work it out for my specific case using this!

Comment: @omsorg if this answers your question sufficiently, you should accept it to prevent it from being bumped up to the front page unnecessarily in the future.

Comment: thanks for the headsup, just done!